# LINQ to DataTable Query date range w/ Lambda Expression

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, datatable, lambda

I need a linq query that will work on a vb datatable to query for the next closest future target date, or, if there is not future date in the database, the target date that has most recently passed.

todays date is 3/28/2014.  If my datatable has dates 3/27, 3/31, 4/1, 4/10 - then i need the query to return 3/31.

What i've got so far is

```
Dim fhQuery1 = From row In dtFileHearing.AsEnumerable() _
               Where row.HearingTypeID = 5 AndAlso row.HearingDateTime > DateTime.Now()
               Order By row.HearingDateTime Ascending _
               Select row _
               Take (1)

Dim fhQuery2 = From row2 In dtFileHearing.AsEnumerable() _
               Where row2.HearingTypeID = 5 AndAlso row2.HearingDateTime <= DateTime.Now()
               Order By row2.HearingDateTime Descending
               Select row2 _
               Take (1)


For Each dr As DataRow In fhQuery1
    If IsDate(dr.Field(Of Date)("HearingDateTime")) Then
       ReplaceValue = dr.Field(Of Date)("HearingDateTime").ToShortDateString()
    End If
Next

If ReplaceValue = String.Empty Then
   For Each dr As DataRow In fhQuery2
       If IsDate(dr.Field(Of Date)("HearingDateTime")) Then
          ReplaceValue = dr.Field(Of Date)("HearingDateTime").ToShortDateString()
       End If
   Next
End If
```

The above code works fine, but i would like it to be more compact by nesting fhQuery1 and fhQuery2 together to yield the appropriate date.

Also, I've discovered I can use dr("ColumnName") rather than dr.Field(Of Type)("ColumnName")

Edit: - I'm thinking perhaps my question is unclear.  fhQuery1 performs a query on a datatable of objects that have future dates and returns the closest date from today.  fhQuery2 performs the same query but returns the object with the most recent past date.  The logic below determines if there is a value in fhQuery1, to use that date.  If fhQuery1 doesn't have a date, then use fhQuery2.

My question is then, using a lambda expression, how would i combine these in to one simple elegant query?

Dim relevantHearing = dtFileHearing.Where(Function(f) f.HearingTypeID = 5 AndAlso f.HearingDateTime > DateTime.Now()) _
                      .OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.HearingDateTime).Take(1) _
                      .Union(dtFileHearing.Where(Function(f) f.HearingTypeID = 5 AndAlso f.HearingDateTime <= DateTime.Now()) _
                                                    .OrderBy(Function(f) f.HearingDateTime) _
                                                    .Take(1)) _
                      .OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.HearingDateTime).FirstOrDefault

This works as well, but it doesn't seem quite as elegant as what i was hoping...I at least was able to use the Union operator to combine both the queries though.

Comment: For Each dr As DataRow In fhQuery1
                        If IsDate(dr.Field(Of Date)("HearingDateTime")) Then
                            ReplaceValue = dr.Field(Of Date)("HearingDateTime").ToShortDateString()
                        End If
                    Next

This works for what I need, but I would still like to see this done in a single nested query.  Thanks!

Comment: Dim Rel As dtFileHearingsRow= dtFileHearings.Where(function(h) h.HearingTypeID = 5) _        .Select(Function(h) New With {.Rank = DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Now, h.HearingDateTime),                     .Item = h}) _        .GroupBy(function(r) If(r.Rank > 0, 1, 0)) _
        .SelectMany(function(g) IF(g.Key = 1, g.OrderBy(function(i) i.Item.HearingDateTime).Take(1).Select(function(r) r.Item),
                       g.OrderByDescending(function(i) i.Item.HearingDateTime).Take(1).Select(function(r) r.Item))) _
        .OrderByDescending(function(h) h.HearingDateTime) _
        .FirstOrDefault